# Can I make mods for Skyrim?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

Can regular owners of the Skyrim game make mods for skyrim? Will it include mod tools, level editors, etc?

If not, are there any customizations that end users can do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The creation kit has now been released and can be found on Steam.

> When we created Skyrim, we set out to make the largest, most engrossing role-playing game we had ever attempted. Now it’s about to get a whole lot bigger, thanks to our amazing modding community.
>
> Mod-makers have a long history with Bethesda Game Studios, bringing to life new quests, locations and characters, as well as making changes to game from subtle tweaks to full-blown overhauls. With the Creation Kit, the same tool we used to create Skyrim, there’s almost no limit to what can be accomplished – and we’re putting that power in your hands.
>   Best of all, access to the Skyrim Workshop and Creation Kit is free for anybody with a Steam account and a copy of Skyrim.
>
> With the Skyrim Workshop, finding and installing your favorite mods is easier than ever before. Mod-makers will also enjoy a streamlined process for uploading mods directly to Steam.

Here is a [link](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/browse/?appid=72850&browsesort=trend&p=1) to the steam workship for Skyrim.

Source: [Creation Kit Wiki](http://www.creationkit.com/Introducing_the_Skyrim_Workshop)

Comment: Yeah... It'll definitely be moddable (on PC), the only question is how long we'll have to wait to get our hands on the TES5 CS.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman: It's done when it's done. :D What won't work (at least not initially) is to mod for consoles. Bethesda announced that they were trying to make it happen, but so far the outlook for this is rather bleak.

Comment: Please update when more information is available on the release of the "TES5 CS" aka "Creation Kit".

Comment: Currently there are already a number of mods available for Skyrim.  The more advanced mods like changing object shapes and adding new areas will have to wait for the Creation Kit.  There are many places to get mods (just search the web for "skyrim mod").  One of the most popular is  [Skyrim Nexus](http://www.skyrimnexus.com)